# c# using statement with double IDisposable

Tags: c#, using, idisposable

I have following statement using `using`:

```
using (var reader = data.CreateCommand(sql).ExecuteDataReader())
```

in this case `data` is some object which internally holds `SqlConnection`. `CreateCommand(sql)` function returns `SqlCommand` and `ExecuteDataReader` returns `SqlDataReader`. Since `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are both `IDisposable`, will they both be disposed by this use of `using` statement?

For now I have done it like this:

```
using (var cmd = data.CreateCommand(sql))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteDataReader())
```

But I would like to know if it's possible to combine them as stated above?

Comment: From the information you've given us, the answer has to be that you need to do it with the separate `using`s.

Comment: Should I provide any more information? Although, I think I've also realized that it won't go with a single using. It would be nice though, especially if there were more usings ;)

Comment: is `data` a custom class you wrote to access database? i mean can you modify its code?

Comment: @Jure - I'll write you up an answer in a second (after I double check the `SqlCommand` class' `Dispose` method and `ExecuteReader` method. However a helpful read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1461836/3645638 **Quote:** *"Any class that instantiates an IDisposable member should implement IDisposable itself, and properly Dispose() of its constituents."*

Comment: Based on my understanding, Disposing the `SqlConnection` would dispose all resources using it, therefore `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` would go with it... That being said, I believe that disposing `SqlCommand` would then dispose `SqlDataReader`. So you don't have to put the `SqlReader` in the `using` statement.

Comment: @Svek disposing `SqlConnection` will not dispose associated `SqlCommand` or reader!

Comment: @S.Serp My answer below illustrates clearer as to what I was trying to say in the comments box.

Comment: @S. Serp: `data` is my custom object (internally it has SqlConnection for db-based stuff). CreateCommand and ExecuteDataReader are also my methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"if it's possible to combine them"* - two `using` are totally fine, because both needs to be disposed.

You can combine them by extracting into method:

```
void RunWithReader(string sql, Action<SQLDataReader> action)
{
    using (var cmd = data.CreateCommand(sql))
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteDataReader())
        action(reader);
}
```

Then you can use lambda

```
RunWithReader("whatever command", reader =>
{
    ... // while(reader.Read() { ... } - this could also be extracted
});
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Matthew Watson's comment. You need to have both of `usings` statemets.
Here is the related question with additional reasoning. [SqlConnection SqlCommand SqlDataReader IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985876/sqlconnection-sqlcommand-sqldatareader-idisposable)

Comment: Interesting, will the garbage collector not just remove the SqlCommand object after reader is destroyed? Edit: no, probably not, as `data` is not destroyed...

Answer (score 2):

The way you have presented your code the inner `IDisposable` (`IDbCommand`) is not disposed.

You have two choices:

You can put it all in one `using` like this:

```
using (IDisposable cmd = data.CreateCommand(), reader = ((IDbCommand)cmd).ExecuteReader())
{
    // code here
}
```

But that is rather cumbersome. The other option is nested `using` statements:

```
using (var cmd = data.CreateCommand())
{
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Other than that you can get a bit complicated and write an extension method to help (sort of) clean it up for you.

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static void Using<T, R>(this T obj, Func<T, R> create, Action<T, R> use) where R : IDisposable
    {
        using (var d = create(obj))
        {
            use(obj, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
data.Using(d => d.CreateCommand(), (d, c) => c.Using(c2 => c2.ExecuteReader(), (c3, r) =>
{
    // code here
}));
```

But perhaps that's not much of an improvement.

Answer (score -1):

### In General

> **You should** `Dispose` **every class that implements** `IDisposable`.

However, your question is specifically dealing with a scenario **where all the resources are all related**, which if my understanding is correct, the Garbage Collector will dispose these resources for you automatically.

---

### The `Finalize()` Method ("Destructors" or "Finalizers")

> The `Finalize()` method makes sure that resources are disposed when
>   the instance is no longer referenced by the application.

**In concert together with the** `Dispose()` **method**

The `Dispose()` method will "release all resources used by the component". Which would mean that this code block (taken from [MSDN's ExecuteReader Method Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)) will properly dispose of all the compenents used by it...

> ```
> using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
> {
>     connection.Open();
>
>     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
>     SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
>     while (reader.Read())
>     {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, when disposing `SqlConnection`, it will properly
>   **release all resources used by the component**. Which means:
>
> - `SqlCommand`
> - `SqlDataReader`
>
>   ** *Note: This has always been my understanding*...

---

Refactoring of the above code to the following:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The main advantage of manually disposing of each resource, would be
>   for a performance gain since we are not processing up to the
>   `Finalize` method (which is relatively a more expensive than doing `Dispose()`.

However, that doesn't mean you want to `Dispose()` everything, as in some cases the `Finalize()` method is a better choice.

---

*Assuming that I am still in good shape so far, and my understanding of the Garbage Collector's behavior is valid.*

I would consider that `SqlCommand` (full code reference [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,6d1f148f36c73572)), would then also dispose of `SqlReader`, which would mean that you could just get away with:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
{
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

which in your case would translate to:

> ```
> using (var cmd = data.CreateCommand(sql))
> {
>     var reader = cmd.ExecuteDataReader();
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1808056/2803565 . also its comment: not disposing a SqlCeCommand, for example, will cause your mobile device to run out of memory quite fast.

Comment: @S.Serp `System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand` and `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` are different.

Comment: yes i know, but as said in comment, this is an example to say its not good idea to don't dispose objects which are `IDisposable`. the issues depends on several params and it is not safe! if you check the source code of `SqlCommand.Dispose`, you see it release something as: `this._cachedMetaData = null;`

Comment: If my understanding is correct, `reader` in the last example would not get disposed, when `cmd` is disposed, because it's not in its own `using` statement?

Comment: @Jure From what I understand, it does get disposed of, as the `cmd` resouce is disposed, the `Finalize()` method would clean it up. It's not *bad* design, just not as tidy as calling the `Dispose()` method.